# Should I close as unclear or duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closing

I saw [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199614/minecraft-how-do-you-give-a-villager-custom-trading) this morning, and while the question wasn't very specific, I still kinda saw what the OP (might) have been getting at, and I had seen a similar question before.

However, since we were uncertain as to what exactly was being asked, I decided to instead of closing as dupe, to close as unclear, then link the related question in a comment.

Is that the right way to go, or should I have dealt with it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not sure what a question is asking then it's better to close as "unclear what you're asking" rather than a duplicate. In fact, unclear what you're asking should be your go to close reason when you're not sure what the question is asking because, well, that's what the close reason is there for. It lets the asker and everyone viewing the question know this question *could* be perfectly fine and on-topic, except we don't really know what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

Pick unclear, then link to the potential duplicate as a comment in case it does help.